# media player setDisplay Ilegal state exception

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a 2 media  players that I want too loop between, so play player1 then swap to player2 then player1 etc. But when I try to set the display for the second one I get an illegal state exception. I looked at the reference page for the media player to check what state `setDisplay()` can't be called in, but it says it can be called when the media player is in any state. Any suggestions as to why this is happening? This only happens when the second media player is called for the second time and it has no problem going from mediaplayer2 to mediaplayer1 with the same implementation.

Log cat

```
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162): java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setVideoSurface(Native Method)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDisplay(MediaPlayer.java:668)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at my.package.MainActivity.onCompletion(MainActivity.java:275)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2013)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 14:16:09.314 E/AndroidRuntime( 8162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you using `release()` and also check for `mediaplayer != null`?

Comment: I'm not using release as I would like to keep the media players buffered to make the transitions smoother